# How to search collection entries from entered text

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Hello I have been google searching an read some few similar question and solution with regards to this problem but due to me being fairly a beginner with nodejs I could not understand those solution and try and implement them myself so I was trying to make a search query to my database collection using mongoose so I wanted to search entire entry of  each document because I can never know what a user will search so I wanted to cater for that.

So I implemented my search that is working(for this project will be suitable because I only want to search houses in different provinces but for another project this approach might and definitely will fail) can I please get help in a way of implementing this search using mongoose

**Code that I implemented to make the search query**

```
router.get("/api/search/:search", async (request, response) => {
  const searchArray = request.params.search.split(" ");
  let results = [];
  let helper = searchArray.length;
  while (helper >= 0) {
    console.log(searchArray[helper]);
    await House.find({ "house_location.province": searchArray[helper] })
      .exec()
      .then((data) => {
        if (data[0]) {
          results.push(data);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    helper--;
  }
  return response.status(200).json(results);
});
```

Please try to be a give a bit detailed answer such that beginner like me can understand please

Comment: Im not sure what you trying to achieve? You want to search particular fields in collection by the text user entered? Correct? For example : I type "brown fox" -> mongo should find all documents where house_location.province === "brown fox"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question right, but based from your code you can simply use the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array)-operator and with the split string values:

```
router.get("/api/search/:search", async (request, response) => {
    const searchArray = request.params.search.split(" ");
    try {
        const results = await House.find({"house_location.province": {$in: searchArray}}).exec()
        return response.status(200).json(results);
    } catch (err) {
        // handle error
        response.status(500).end();
    }

});
```

If you want to match substrings you could also use `$in` but in combination with regular expressions as they show in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#in-expressions).

For more sophisticated text searches check this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/

Comment: So with this code snippet will the $in take each string to check all documents if the string exist? if exists it will return me the data?

Comment: Yes exactly, it will perform a string sensitive search on the specified field for all documents.